# Import code from another source (python) (windows 7,8,10)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem. Two different codes are in the same directory, but I cannot do the following:

`from py_file1 import *`

Considering that this is `py_file2.py` and the directory looks like this:

```
New Folder >
    py_file1.py
    py_file2.py
```

I want be able to do this:

```
#file1 contents:
def a():
    print("A function in file1.")
```

And this:

```
#file2 contents
from py_file1 import *
a()
```

And when run in the interpreter, there is no `ImportError`.

```
>>>
A function in file1.
>>>
```

Comment: How did you come across this problem, because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Can't reproduce on ubuntu.

Comment: @Fiskie Well, I have two python programs in the same folder, and I want one of them to run the other - I want py_file2 to run or `import` py_file1

Comment: @tobias_k, not really - I have two programs on my flash drive, both in the same folder. Could you explain the `dir()` function for me?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I am using windows

Comment: It looks like you're current directory is not the same as where the files are stored. Thus the latter is not in path.

Comment: @tynn You were right - my current directory wasn't the same. Thanks. But out of interest, what would you do if two modules were in completely different folders?

Comment: Please put the whole info: a minimal verifiable example of the problem, the expected output and what's the actual output. I don't see any problem in your statement (nor a question).

Comment: @tglaria It was an error on my part - but how do you suggest I improve the question?

Comment: @BUZZYSIN put the code that gives you a problem (a minimal example, don't insert your whole project), what's the expected result and what result you're having. If you found your error, then write what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're current directory is not the same as where the files are stored. Thus the latter is not in the path.

You should put the modules somewhere in the search path of python or add the directory the files are in to the search path:

```
from sys import path
path.insert(1, "path/to/lib")
from py_file1 import *
a()
```

Comment: Shouldn't he get an import error if the library isn't imported? He says "And when run in the interpreter, there is no `ImportError`".